# multiple query report using counts

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a report which has multiple counts:

```
SELECT 
C.REGION,
COUNT (C.id) AS 'No of customers',
COUNT (C.id) AS 'No of new customers', 
COUNT (C.id) As 'No of waiting customers',
COUNT (C.id) As 'Total No of help available'

FROM CUSTOMER C
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERPARAMETER CP ON C.ID=CP.ID 
WHERE (C.DATEOFBIRTH IS NULL)
GROUP BY C.REGION
```

The problem is each of my counts are populated by different queries. What is the best way to create a multiple query report?

It doesnt allow me to write a select statement for each count... I need to write a DIFFERENT query for each count. But it wont let me.

Comment: There is no **best** way. Besides that - hard to tell without table structure, example data and expected outcome.

Comment: Best in what sense? Ease of maintenance? Performance? Readability? Obfusication for the purpose of increased job security?

Comment: We can you show me an example method?

Comment: @PriceCheaperton: Sorry, but no. We deal here only with very specific problems. So please expand your question and with enough detail we may solve this specific problem.

Comment: The problem is, it doesnt allow me to do a select statement in the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information about the schema of the table, i can point you to the right direction:

```
SELECT C.REGION,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <...>) AS 'No of customers',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <...>) AS 'No of new customers', 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <...>) As 'No of waiting customers',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <...>) As 'Total No of help available'
FROM CUSTOMER C ....
```

Replace `<...>` with the conditions you need for each column and you should be set.

See reference for these kind of subquerys: [Subqueries Used in Place of an Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189623%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: no because i get the following: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression`

Comment: majority of my subqueries will look like this: `SELECT
    (SELECT C.REGION
     FROM CUSTOMER C
     INNER JOIN CUSTOMERPARAMETER CP ON C.ID=CP.ID
     WHERE (C.DATEOFDEATH IS NULL)
     GROUP BY C.REGION) AS 'No of customers',...`

Comment: and i have slightly different criteria for each sub query.

Comment: Didn't you want the COUNT? for each Region? for that, you would have only one value returned in each of the subqueries. you shouldn't need the group by in the subqueries, since you only want the count. If you could put the query on sqlfiddle it would be easier to help.

Comment: No i just want to display the region.

Comment: See this for example: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6704d/4) You can see what i mean

Comment: @PriceCheaperton. Can you see the reasoning for this approach? I think it's what you are trying to do.

Comment: I removed the group by and it works but it doesnt return the counts based on the regions.. any ideas?

Comment: You have to add the inner constraint by region. Like on the example i showed you, your region is the other_col. If you want to show your script in sqlfiddle, i can help you better.

Comment: Were you able to adapt it to your problem?